# Reading MLDv2 queries using an IPv6 socket

Tags: ipv6, socket, multicast, icmp

I have [mrd6](https://github.com/hugosantos/mrd6) installed on my raspberry pi.  It registers with a local interface (tun0) and periodically transmits MLDv2 queries over it.

According to [[RFC3810](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3810)], MLDv2 message types are a subset of ICMPv6 messages, and are identified in IPv6 packets by a preceding Next Header value of 58 (0x3a).  They are sent with a link-local IPv6 Source Address, an IPv6 Hop Limit of 1, and an IPv6 Router Alert option [[RFC2711](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2711)] in a Hop-by-Hop Options header.

I can confirm that I'm seeing these packets periodically over tun0:

```
pi@machine:~ $ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 ip6 -vv -XX

01:22:52.125915 IP6 (flowlabel 0x71df6, hlim 1, next-header Options (0)
payload length: 36) 
fe80::69bf:be2d:e087:9921 > ip6-allnodes: HBH (rtalert: 0x0000) (padn)
[icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, multicast listener query v2 [max resp delay=10000]
[gaddr :: robustness=2 qqi=125]
            0x0000:  6007 1df6 0024 0001 fe80 0000 0000 0000  `....$..........
            0x0010:  69bf be2d e087 9921 ff02 0000 0000 0000  i..-...!........
            0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0001 3a00 0502 0000 0100  ........:.......
            0x0030:  8200 b500 2710 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ....'...........
            0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0000 027d 0000            .........}..
```

I have a socket set up in my application on tun0 as follows, since I expect these to be ICMP packets:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6); // ICMP

// ... bind this socket to tun0

  int interfaceIndex = // tun0 interface Index
  int mcastTTL = 10;
  int loopBack = 1;

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_MULTICAST_IF,
                 &interfaceIndex,
                 sizeof(interfaceIndex))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_MULTICAST_IF:: ");
  }

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP,
                 &loopBack,
                 sizeof(loopBack))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP:: ");
  }

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS,
                 &mcastTTL,
                 sizeof(mcastTTL))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS::  ");
  }

  struct ipv6_mreq mreq6 = {{{{0}}}};
  MEMCOPY(&mreq6.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr, sourceAddress, 16);
  mreq6.ipv6mr_interface = interfaceIndex;

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_JOIN_GROUP,
                 &mreq6,
                 sizeof(mreq6))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_JOIN_GROUP::  ");
  }
```

Setting up the socket this way, I can receive ICMP echo requests, replies to my own address, and multicasts sent using the link-local multicast address.  However, I don't see ***any*** MLDv2 queries.

Here's my receive loop:

```
  uint8_t received[1000] = { 0 };
  struct sockaddr_storage peerAddress = { 0 };
  socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(peerAddress);
  socklen_t addressLength = sizeof(peerAddress);

  int receivedLength = recvfrom(sockfd,
                                received,
                                sizeof(received),
                                0,
                                (struct sockaddr *)&peerAddress,
                                &addressLength);

  if (receivedLength > 0) {
    // Never get here for MLDv2 queries.
  }
```

Researching this a bit further, I discovered the IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT socket option, which the man page describes as follows:

```
IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT
Pass forwarded packets containing a router alert hop-by-hop option to this socket.
Only allowed for SOCK_RAW sockets.  The tapped packets are not forwarded by the
kernel, it is the user's responsibility to send them out again.  Argument is a
pointer to an integer.  A positive integer indicates a router alert option value
to intercept.  Packets carrying a router alert option with a value field
containing this integer will be delivered to the socket.  A negative integer
disables delivery of packets with router alert options to this socket.
```

So I figured I was missing this option, and tried setting it as follows.  [[RFC2710](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2710)] 0 means Multicast Listener Discovery message.

```
  int routerAlertOption = 0;

  if (setsockopt(listener->socket,
                 IPPROTO_IPV6,
                 IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT,
                 &routerAlertOption,
                 sizeof(routerAlertOption))
      < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt:: IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT::  ");
  }
```

However, this gives me the ENOPROTOOPT error (errno 92).  Some more Googling (http://www.atm.tut.fi/list-archive/usagi-users-2005/msg00317.html) led me to the fact that you can't set the IPV6_ROUTER_ALERT option with the IPPROTO_ICMPV6 protocol.  It needs a socket defined using the IPPROTO_RAW protocol.

However, defining my socket as:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

means I'm not able to receive any ICMP packets in my recvfrom anymore.

---

TL;DR: How do I read MLDv2 queries using an IPv6 socket?

---

***edit (answer):***
It appears conventional implementations of Linux will drop MLDv2 packets when passing them to an ICMPV6 socket.  Why this is, I'm not sure.  (Could be because of the next-header option.)

I went with an approach of reading raw packets on the tun0 interface.  I followed the ping6_ll.c example here: http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html.

It uses a socket with (SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_ALL).  You can also set some SOL_PACKET options to filter on specific multicast rules on your interface.